# Resolving nested transactions when using realm and pagination

Tags: android, database, pagination, realm, realm-list

I'm using realm for persistence in my app.

At the moment, I have a list of items in a simple pagination fashion.

- Make a server request
- Get items back
- Update the UI
- Save ***list*** to realm
- User scrolls to the end of the list, get the next set of elements and repeat
  above

Realm code:

```
    try {
      mDbManager.beginTransaction();
        mDbManager.copyToRealm(list);
        mDbManager.commitTransaction();
        Logger.v("Realm ", "Copied list to realm");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e("Realm Something went wrong ", e);
    }
```

I get the error because of this pagination loop:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction().
```

I also tried closing the database after each commit but that didn't help.

How can I achieve this storage and resolve the nested transactions?

Or can anyone suggest a better design structure for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure that while you catch the exception , you closes the transaction by `mDbManager.closetransaction`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Realm.isInTransaction()` to check if you have an open transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to aviod this :

```
 beginTransaction 
beginTransaction 

commitTransaction 
commitTransaction
```

you should do something like this :

```
beginTransaction 
commitTransaction

beginTransaction 
commitTransaction
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there're beginTransaction() before your code try to close it.

Comment: Sorry i'm confused, so i shouldn't beginTransaction if i want to store a new object?